# Can I configure memory separately from compute?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-billing

I'm comparing GCF & cloud competitors, and I see that GCF charges separately for memory (GB/s) & compute (GHz/s) from their pricing page:

https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing

I'm wondering if this means I can configure memory size separately from compute size? e.g. can I scale a memory expensive function to have e.g. 4GB of memory & only 1.4GHz of compute? Or do I have to stick to one of the 7 types as per "Cloud Functions can be provisioned as one of 7 types". In the 4GB example above, that would mean I'd need to have 4.8GHz in addition to 4GB. If I could configure these separately, I might be able to save some money.

Comment: Not yet. Or use Cloud Run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They cannot be configured independently.  The documentation says:

> Cloud Functions can be provisioned as one of 7 types:

And that needs to be taken literally - there are only 7 options for configuring the instances that run a function.  You are effectively paying a static rate for GB-GHz-seconds of time for your chosen config, as the table shows.